# XSL: Sorting on a Hybrid XML File

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file which is an amalgam of two smaller XML files. While each of the two files has different enclosing tags, both have a particular field of the same name on which I would like to sort, using XSLT 1.0 only.

I have created the following XML / XSLT files to demonstrate the problem.

The **desired** output is: `1,2,3,4,5,6`

But the **actual** output is: `1,3,5,2,4,6`

In other words, each sub-file (`<DataSet1>` and`<DataSet2>`) is being sorted correctly, but the desired result is to have the file as a whole sorted correctly.

How can I correct this problem? (Please note that I cannot alter the XML file in any way below the level of `<DataSet1>` and`<DataSet2>`.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xml-file>
    <DataSet1>
        <Table1>
            <Rank>1</Rank>
        </Table1>
        <Table1>
            <Rank>5</Rank>
        </Table1>
        <Table1>
            <Rank>3</Rank>
        </Table1>
    </DataSet1>
    <DataSet2>
        <Table2>
            <Rank>6</Rank>
        </Table2>
        <Table2>
            <Rank>2</Rank>
        </Table2>
        <Table2>
            <Rank>4</Rank>
        </Table2>
    </DataSet2>
</xml-file>
```

Here is the XSLT file I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <xsl:template match="DataSet1|DataSet2">
        <xsl:apply-templates>
            <xsl:sort select="Rank" order="ascending" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table1">
        <xsl:value-of select="Rank"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Table2">
        <xsl:value-of select="Rank"/><br/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Not understanding your question here. If you can't split each `<DataSet>` tag how do you expect your tables to be sorted according to your criteria? Can you include your output as full XML?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that this template:

```
<xsl:template match="DataSet1|DataSet2">
```

is actually instantiated twice - once for each DataSet. And each instance sorts it own nodes, so in the end you get two groups of Ranks, each sorted internally. Try instead:

```
<xsl:template match="/xml-file">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="DataSet1/Table1 | DataSet2/Table2">
        <xsl:sort select="Rank" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Table1 | Table2">
    <xsl:value-of select="Rank"/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
<xsl:template match="/xml-file">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*/Rank">
        <xsl:sort select="." data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Rank">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/><br/>
</xsl:template>
```